# Seeing the shadow of a black hole

Tags: black-holes, astronomy, shadow

Why can't we see the shadow of a black hole cast on Earth. Shouldn't the black hole block some light from a star or a galaxy far behind as they line up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will block some light. But barely anyone would notice if Gliese 581 were suddenly covered up by a black hole, and it's only 20 light-years away. The closest known black hole is *1600* light years away. You'd need some pretty sharp vision.

Also, you're going on the assumption that black holes block light like normal objects, which they don't. They do it like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_lens#mediaviewer/File:Black_hole_lensing_web.gif

Black holes are weird :)

Comment: [THE DEATH OF GENERAL RELATIVITY LURKS IN A BLACK HOLE’S SHADOW](http://www.wired.com/2016/01/the-death-of-general-relativity-lurks-in-a-black-holes-shadow/) “The Event Horizon Telescope has the capability to produce the highest-resolution images in the history of astronomy”, Broderick says. “That means, for the first time, we can see what happens right down in the immediate vicinity of black hole event horizons.”

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons is that very little light actually gets to earth from this galaxy or star, so the change in the amount of light coming in is negligible.  You don't "see" any shadow because there was almost no light coming to the earth in the first place.
The next reason, the more important one, is that the light from other galaxies/stars fill in the shadow that would be created by the black hole.  For instance, if that Galaxy were the only source of light, then technically the black hole would cast a shadow, but in reality light from other stars fills in that shadow.

Comment: Not to mention gravitational lensing...  I'd say the real answer is that the black hole is tiny and occupies such a small angle in our sky that we don't even have the angular resolution needed to see such a small thing. But we do see the gravitational lensing.

Comment: visible wavelengths aren't great of seeing a black thing agains the black background... have you ever seen a shadow of an object in front of a distant star? occluding all wavelengths is what a black hold does.