# Would a black hole cast a shadow?

Tags: black-holes, astronomy, shadow

Okay, so I've been wondering and this is a simple question and I cannot find an answer anywhere.
Would a blackhole the size of the Moon (event horizon) black out the Sun in a "Lunar eclipse"? 
My theory is that the light from the son would bend around the black hole and still hit the earth one way or another. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Yep. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_lens#/media/File:Black_hole_lensing_web.gif) is a simulation of a black hole 'eclipsing' a distant galaxy.

Comment: Looked at from afar what you see is a sort of 'halo' of light around the edge of the thing, with a central black disk.  Have a look at [this](https://rantonels.github.io/starless/) which is a raytracer for black holes.  The images Interstellar were also fairly realistic I think.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Seeing the shadow of a black hole](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/161524/)

Comment: A black hole with an event horizon the size of the Moon would be *far* more massive than the Moon, which has its own implications. Compare [Black Hole Moon](https://what-if.xkcd.com/129/).

Comment: Google for "Gravitational Lensing"